# PutExtra getExtra in RecyclerView not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need help.
I create android recyclerview cardview project, when data list from cardview clicked (use putExtra dan getExtra) will call new activity , but not working (in new activity blank no content).

**this my code (CardViewAndroidAdapter.java) my full code error when i paste in here - ask in stackoverflow**

```
   holder.btnDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("PUT_PHOTO", getListAndroid().get(position).getPhoto());
                intent.putExtra("PUT_DESK", getListAndroid().get(position).getDesk());

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**this my code (DetailActivity.java) my full code error when i paste in here**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String GET_PHOTO = "get_photo";
private static final String GET_DESK = "get_desk";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Detail Version");
    getIncomingIntent();
}

private void getIncomingIntent() {
    if(getIntent().hasExtra(GET_PHOTO)&&getIntent().hasExtra(GET_DESK)){
        String getPhoto=getIntent().getStringExtra(GET_PHOTO);
        String getDesk = getIntent().getStringExtra(GET_DESK);

    TextView detail=findViewById(R.id.tv_detail);
    detail.setText(getDesk);
        ImageView img_item_photo=findViewById(R.id.img_item_photo);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(getPhoto)
                .into(img_item_photo);

    }
}
```

Comment: `if(getIntent().hasExtra(GET_PHOTO)&&getIntent().hasExtra(GET_DESK))`?  And you have put keys `PUT_PHOTO` and `PUT_DESK`  .. So how you suppose to get it work . Make the keys same .

Comment: thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
intent.putExtra("PUT_PHOTO", getListAndroid().get(position).getPhoto());
intent.putExtra("PUT_DESK", getListAndroid().get(position).getDesk());
```

with this:

```
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.GET_PHOTO, getListAndroid().get(position).getPhoto());
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.GET_DESK, getListAndroid().get(position).getDesk());
```

It should work now.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping, it work. why getPhoto still blank , what's wrong ?